# Extracting several strings from a range of cells

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula, vba

I have couple thousand of cell which I need to extract document numbers out from. Cells have no format what so ever, but every Document Number starts with "Doc#-"
So for example

B2:

```
This is an example cell showing a doc number DOC#-12351-2432-1b and a second document DOC#-2342-RTF-DD-09, there may be several more or only one.
```

I am looking for a way to extract all the document numbers as individual numbers, into separate cells, line, etc. What would the best way to go about this?

Current I have some extremely rough Formula.

```
=MID($B2,find("DOC#-",$b2,1),FIND(" ",$b2,find("DOC#-",$b2,1))-find("Doc#-",$b2,1)
```

Which: Finds the first doc, find a space after it, returns the number with MID.

Thinking VBA is likely the way to solve this, but I'm stumped on how.

Comment: Just a thought but maybe (since there seems to be no real consistent formatting to the DOC number) highlight the cells and use Text to Columns with a space delimiter.  From your example that'll at least extract them.

Comment: Would love to, as that would make it super simple. However you can not enter more that a single character for a delimiter in Text-to-cols, and there are too many "#"s and "-"s that I can't reliably use those singularly.

Comment: Oh! Find "DOC#-", Replace "@DOC#-". Now I can Text to Col. Then some formula to remove the trailing text. Guess thanks after all Mrbungle

Comment: I used your example and used the Space delimiter and it extracted the "DOC#-12351-2432-1b" and "DOC#-2342-RTF-DD-09," into separate cells. From there you can at least do something with it.

Comment: There ya go, no problem :)

Comment: Where do you want to put the document numbers once you have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the cells you wish to process and run this small macro:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim i As Long, V As String, K As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        V = Replace(r.Value, ",", " ")
        ary = Split(V, "DOC#-")
        K = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(ary)
            bry = Split(ary(i), " ")
            bry(0) = "DOC#-" & bry(0)
            r.Offset(0, K).Value = bry(0)
            K = K + 1
        Next i
    Next r
End Sub
```

It will look for either a **space** or a **comma** to terminate the document number.  Here is an example of input/output:

[image]

Comment: Keep this anyway. Less steps. Thank you.

Comment: Great answer, although would love to see array formula based answer.

Comment: @zx8754 It is MUCH more difficult for me to construct formulas than write VBA.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent for me the opposite :)

Answer (score 0):

A variant array/regexp approach for speed

```
Sub GetDoc()
Dim X
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegexMC As Object
Dim objRegexM As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long
Dim lngCnt2 As Long

X = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
ReDim Preserve X(1 To UBound(X, 1), 1 To 100)

Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "DOC#[-\w]+"
For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(X)
    If .test(X(lngCnt, 1)) Then
    lngCnt2 = 2
        Set objRegexMC = .Execute(X(lngCnt, 1))
            For Each objRegexM In objRegexMC
                X(lngCnt, lngCnt2) = objRegexM
            lngCnt2 = lngCnt2 + 1
            Next
    End If
Next
End With

[a1].Resize(UBound(X, 1), UBound(X, 2)) = X

End Sub
```